# Does Kicad (pcbnew) allow dragging nodes — i.e. junctions between track segments?

Tags: pcb, kicad

I am starting to use Kicad and am used to gEDA suite. The latter allows dragging anything in `pcb`: tracks, track segment ends, footprints, selected objects... For instance, you can drag the end of a track segment in gEDA `pcb` by clicking one end with a left click and drag it so only that very end is dragged while the other stays in place.

I just couldn't figure out how to do that in Kicad; all I could do was drag the clicked/selected segment. On the other end I tried myself at grab-and-drag a whole track while conforming to the DRC rules, keeping the net connected, which feature gEDA doesn't have. That said I find this feature very convenient.

So is it possible to drag track segment ends in Kicad or do I have to change paradigm? I didn't find any info on that very topic so either it's too trivial to be mentioned (you can all me dumb) or it's not implemented because something more useful is in place...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I finally found the answer on my own so I'm posting it here in case someone, just like me, happens to wonder. Put Kicad in OpenGL view mode and drag vias, tracks, track corners or whatever you want — provided you set DRC and routing constraints, of course. It is explained in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CCG4daPvuVI) on Youtube.

To drag items while in OpenGL view mode, select `Add single track` on the rightmost toolbar and then press <kbd>D</kbd> over the track/node you want to drag (no click required). The router will shove tracks or move the one you're dragging around according to the routing preferences you previously set. Press <kbd>E</kbd> while adding a (single) track to set routing preferences.

Comment: I was hoping this mode would be available for graphic lines / polygons / line segments, but *Move* is the only option / hotkey and operates on the whole segment. However, the **OpenGL mode allows selection and dragging of the line segment nodes**.

Comment: Yes, this is a great feature! Note that they have not yet implemented it for footprints/parts, however. If you move a part, the tracks are unfortunately disconnected. If you'd like them to implement a proper "drag" feature on parts on your PCB too, go to my feature request here (https://bugs.launchpad.net/kicad/+bug/1803260) and click the little tiny icon at the top to say this bug affects you too, and to give it more "fire" (icon on the top right) to get the developers' attention.